# Выборка только уникальных значений из подмассивов массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив такого вида:

```
[
    [1,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Cars"}],
    [2,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}],
    [2,"Toyota Corolla",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}]
]
```

Мне нужно получить массив, в котором будут только уникальные имена машин, без id тегов и прочего. Я делаю так:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

unicCars = cars.filter(onlyUnique);
```

Если скармливать мой массив этой функции, она считает все поля разными, т.к. сравнивает не только имена машин. Я понадеялся, что если подсказать что сравнивать нужно только значения по ключу `value[1]` - то будет то что нужно!

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value[1]) === index;
}
```

Но так не работает. Как всё-таки получить уникальные имена?

Comment: И название машині всегда будет под индексом 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `value[1]` не работает, потому что `value[1]` при этом сравнивается с другими элементами массива (`value`), а не с "под-элементами" (`value[1]`)

C заранее сформированным массивом имён машин (`value[1]`) первоначальный вариант будет работать:

```js
let cars = [
    [1,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Cars"}],
    [2,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}],
    [2,"Toyota Corolla",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}]
];

let carNames = cars.map(car => car[1]);

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let uniqueCarNames = carNames.filter(onlyUnique);
console.log(uniqueCarNames);
```

Данное решение работает за O(n^2), поэтому для больших массивов стоит попробовать что-то более быстро работающее. Например, [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (или реализовать аналогичную логику вручную, если нужна поддержка IE):

```js
let cars = [
    [1,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Cars"}],
    [2,"Porsche 911",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}],
    [2,"Toyota Corolla",{"id":1,"section":1,"tag":"Parts"}]
];

let carNames = cars.map(car => car[1]);
let uniqueCarNames = [...new Set(carNames)];
console.log(uniqueCarNames);
```

Comment: Не знаю какой вариант по скорости лучше, но последний выглядит просто замечательно и отлично работает (IE мне не нужен) Спасибо всем большой!

Comment: @NikolayGrigoryev по скорости должен быть лучше второй вариант (для больших объёмов данных). Для небольших данных (сотня-другая) не принципиально